# How can i get all dependency from idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm writing an idea plugin. I want to analyze all dependencies from current pom. I want to do it by inspection. When user first opens this pom.xml and the inspection will be activitied. How can i get all gav(groupId, artifactId,version) from curren pom.xml.

Comment: I'd recommend you raise a this issue at ["IntelliJ IDEA Open API and Plugin Development"](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development) so that the IntelliJ platform developer could provide the right solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.